# Getting value of unknown component

Tags: java, swing, oop, instanceof

I am building my GUI's input dynamically based on what type of input is required, so for example:

If I require a `double`and a `boolean` then the type of components the GUI creates are a `JTextField` and a `JRadioButton`.

I define what I want each type's input method to be statically like so:

```
private static Map<InputType, Class<? extends Component>> typeComponentMap = new HashMap<InputType, Class<? extends Component>>();

static {
    typeComponentMap.put(InputType.INTEGER, JTextField.class);
    typeComponentMap.put(InputType.DOUBLE, JTextField.class);
    typeComponentMap.put(InputType.BOOLEAN, JRadioButton.class);
    typeComponentMap.put(InputType.STRING, JTextField.class);
}
```

I am facing a problem when then trying to read the value of the component back to one of those types (into a stream)

My method currently looks something like this:

```
public static void writeComponentValue(ObjectOutputStream stream, InputType type, Component component)
```

Now there's no method like *getValue* in `java.awt.Component`, so I can only see one option which is to check the for a subclass using `instanceof` and go from there... but I was hoping there's a better way?

The created stream is intended to be passed to another object which is intended to not know anything about how information about the GUI.

Comment: *"`double` and a `boolean` then the type of components the GUI creates are a `JTextField` and a `JRadioButton`"*  Why not `JSpinner` & `JCheckBox`?

Comment: It could be those types if necessary, it'd just require changing the class in the map. I'm just using those types for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an interface that requires a getInput method and make subclasses for all of the JComponents that implement the interface.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a handler for each JComponent type that you need to create, and register it instead of the JComponent itself. Each handler would have a `getValue` method that would call the appropriate method on it's JComponent.